# GA4 Admin API - Data Import support

Tags: google-analytics-api

GA4 Admin API https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1

there's no support for data import feature ?
is it on roadmap if anyone knows?

(Equivalent Old UA Management API used to support this - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/data-import)

Comment: there are a lot of things in ua that are not supported by ga4 that's because these are two completely different systems.   google doesn't release a road map for ga4 anyone who Did know about the road map would be under nda and not be able to answer your question.

Comment: I recommend filling out the  [contact-us](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/help#contact-us) form

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo  thank you for the link - just did!

Comment: UPDATE: Google just filed the feature request.. no public link to shared to issue tracker

Comment: I will ask next time I have a meeting with them

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo thank you - there’s pretty good use cases were missing out on .

Comment: TBH there are a lot of things that are not supported in GA4.